# Python image pixel access is very slow

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm playing around with different transform coding such as the DWT, DCT and DFT. I've been questioning my approach to the data structure I'm using when it comes to execution time. Here is an example below, say I want to analyze every individual pixel in an image, perhaps to perform encoding of some sort. All I'm doing here is loading each pixel on the same variable "a" to demonstrate a very generic example. This code snippet takes around 66mS which is quite slow for me. Is there a better approach to Image processing when it comes to individual reading and writing of pixels?

```
class Example():

   def __init__(self):
       self.load_image("lena_312.png") #312 by 312

    def load_image(self, directory):
       self.img = cv2.imread(directory)
       self.height,self.width,self.channel = self.img.shape
       self.img_org = np.matrix(self.img[:,:,0]) #Image is greyscale

    def test(self):
       for j in range(0,self.height):
           for i in range(0,self.width):
                a = self.img_org[j,i]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    EX = Example()
    start = time.time()
    EX.test()
    print time.time()-start
```

Comment: Python is a great glue language, but you need something faster for pixel loops. People usually use C/C++ for performance, but of course that's rather painful to develop in if you're used to Python. I've seen javascript used for this kind of thing: it's surprisingly fast, and if you're careful, not as awful as everyone says. For example, here's a JPEG decoder in pure javascript https://github.com/eugeneware/jpeg-js/blob/master/lib/decoder.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure Python per-pixel access will expectedly be very slow. Python lists and Python integers have a huge overhead for numeric-heavy operations that normally rely on CPU caches and pipelining.

Consider using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageChops.html), or [numpy / scipy to do massive bitmap operations](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/), or at least try using [Cython](http://cython.org/) if you must code your custom algorithm in unrestricted Python.